# Gateway NV53 Series - capacitive touch key

Tags: laptop

I have [Gateway NV53 Series](http://support.gateway.com/ca/en/s/notebook/2009/gateway/nv/nv53/NV53nv.shtml)  and recently it stoped to work - not respond to nothing and just stay on with the capacitive touch key as in the follow picture . What does that touch key mean(the lighted key)   ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your numlock is on - I don't think its a capasitive key, just an indicator lamp. The actual button should be somewhere near your delete key or keypad cluster. The only picture I can find of the keyboard is horrid but I've highlighted one possible key

[image]